# Generic math in Rust without Copy (std::ops::Add, etc.)

Tags: rust

As part of a "learn Rust" project, I've been working through some Project Euler problems, in which it would be convenient to have a few generic math functions.  As an example, let's say I want to write a generic "square" function.  If I can live with the builtin numeric types (all of which I believe are Copy), I can write this:

```
fn square<A>(n: A) -> A
where
    A: Mul<Output = A> + Copy,
{
    n.mul(n)
}
```

This seems to work fine.  But what if I want to use a numeric type that is not Copy?   Say I'm using a bignum library in which numbers are not Copy, but which implements std::ops::Mul.  I would have thought I could do this:

```
fn square_ref<'a, A>(n: &'a A) -> A
where
    A: Mul<&'a A, Output = A>,
{
    n.mul(n)
}
```

but that gets me the following error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*n` which is behind a shared reference
  --> src/main.rs:16:5
   |
16 |     n.mul(n)
   |     ^ move occurs because `*n` has type `A`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Why does the call to `mul` insist on resolving to type A, instead of &A?  Just to be clear, my question isn't really about generic math in Rust -- I'm hoping that figuring out how to do this sort of thing, or learning why it can't be done, will help me better understand the language in general.

Comment: Another option is to require `Clone` instead of `Copy`: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=56fc73e528c5f045ca03ccb3cfc63b74 Primitive types will implement `Clone` the same as they do `Copy`, and bignums will have `Clone`. Also note that you don't need to write `n.mul(n)` in `square` and in `square_ref`, you can write `n * n` because `*` invokes the `Mul` trait.

Comment: I would not advice to clone a bigint if you can avoid it, in fact, clone should always be avoid when possible.

Comment: @Stargateur That's good general advice, but there are situations where `clone()` is quite appropriate, e.g. when implementing `Mul` in terms of `MulAssign`. It's important to be aware of the _option_ to request `Clone`, which is the closest equivalent of `Copy` one has for all kinds of numbers (and which will be as performant as `Copy` on primitive nums).

Comment: @user4815162342 I don't see what suddenly you talk about MulAssign.

Comment: @Stargateur It's an example of where cloning numbers is put to good use. Binary arithmetic operations such as multiplication usually come in two forms, a destructive one (the `*=`) and a preserving one (`*`). One way to avoid duplication is to implement the more basic one, `*=`, and trivially provide `*` as `let new = self.clone(); new *= other; new`.  In that case `clone()` is not something to avoid, but actually expresses the intent of the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to bound `&'a A` to be `Mul`, **not** `A`:

```rust
use std::ops::Mul;

fn square_ref<A>(n: &A) -> A
where
    // note the &'a A instead of just A
    for<'a> &'a A: Mul<&'a A, Output = A>,
{
    n.mul(n)
}
```

Comment: Well that was embarrassingly simple.  I didn't realize that was even permissible syntax.  Thank you.

Comment: I note that the original answer did not use the `where for` syntax, but suggested only that the type constraint be `&'a A: Mul<&'a A, Output = A>`.  That seems to work fine. What is the purpose/benefit of the additional syntax?